# CSS-Not able to place a list of Images side by side

Tags: html, css, image

I have a list of CSS Images which needs to be aligned side by side. By that I mean two adjacent Images should share a common border. So, in case there are 20 Images, I would like to stack them in rows of 4 each which can change depending on the screen size. Currently, there is white space between Images which I clearly don't want. I have attached a JS-Fiddle to show what I am doing.

Kindly help

CSS

```
 .photo-grid {

    margin: 1em auto;

    max-width: 300%;

    text-align: center;

}



.photo-grid li {



    display: inline-block;

    margin: 1em;

    width: 125px;

}



.photo-grid img {

    display: block;

    height: auto;

    max-width: 100%;

}



.photo-grid figure {

    height: 125px;

    overflow: hidden;

    position: relative;

    width: 125px;

}



.photo-grid figcaption {

    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);

    color: white;

    display: table;

    height: 100%;

    left: 0;

    opacity: 0;

    position: absolute;

    right: 0;

    top: 0;

    z-index: 100;

}



.photo-grid figcaption p {

    display: table-cell;

    font-size: 1.5em;

    position: relative;

    top: -40px;

    width: 289px;

    vertical-align: middle;

}


.photo-grid li:hover figcaption {

    opacity: 1;

}
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajivsr2309/b627h6ce/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the space between images, the easiest way is probably to remove any white space in the HTML between the elements. Your images are set to `inline-block` which means white space between the elements will be preserved just like any other inline element (like `span` or `a` or whatever).

Another way is to set `font-size: 0` on the container, which will make the spaces between the elements `0` size, removing them from the display.

Another way is to `float` the images, which will make them block level elements (so white space isn't preserved) and stack them next to one another.

```css
img {
  max-width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}

.font-zero {
  font-size: 0;
}

.float {
  overflow: auto;
}
.float img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://static4.businessinsider.com/image/56c640526e97c625048b822a-480/donald-trump.jpg"><img src="http://static4.businessinsider.com/image/56c640526e97c625048b822a-480/donald-trump.jpg"><img src="http://static4.businessinsider.com/image/56c640526e97c625048b822a-480/donald-trump.jpg">

<div class="font-zero">
  <img src="http://static4.businessinsider.com/image/56c640526e97c625048b822a-480/donald-trump.jpg">
  <img src="http://static4.businessinsider.com/image/56c640526e97c625048b822a-480/donald-trump.jpg">
  <img src="http://static4.businessinsider.com/image/56c640526e97c625048b822a-480/donald-trump.jpg">
</div>

<div class="float">
  <img src="http://static4.businessinsider.com/image/56c640526e97c625048b822a-480/donald-trump.jpg">
  <img src="http://static4.businessinsider.com/image/56c640526e97c625048b822a-480/donald-trump.jpg">
  <img src="http://static4.businessinsider.com/image/56c640526e97c625048b822a-480/donald-trump.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: I have removed the spacing in my HTML elements but it didn't work. I tried setting the font-size to 0 which works but then the text doesn't appear when I hover over an Image. I tried setting the float values but unfortunately, it didn't work. I have updated my JS Fiddle, please have a look at it.

Comment: @user3402248 your jsfiddle link 404's

Comment: @user3402248 you have hard defined widths on elements and default margins on `figure` that need to be removed, then I removed the space between the `li`'s in your HTML that are set to `inline-block` https://jsfiddle.net/b627h6ce/5/

Comment: It works great! Now the Images are aligned perfectly! Thank You!

Comment: There is only one more thing, once I hover over an Image, the black background takes up only half of the width of the Image. It should actually cover the whole Image. I tried modifying the width, but it didn't work. The width of the Image is 125px. Could you please help https://jsfiddle.net/b627h6ce/8/

Answer (score 1):

Fix your margins. If you have undesired white space between the pictures, that is likely due to your margin of 1em. Put a top and bottom margin if you want, but don't do an all around one.

Comment: I have removed the margins, but unfortunately the spacing still exists. I have updated my JS Fiddle, please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to make a class group of 25% width -> `col25`.
Then you make three classes for each image one for small devices -> `.scol25`,
one for medium devices -> `.mcol25`, and one  for large devices -> `.lcol25`.

Then you remove the margin between the images and make the have box sizing border box.

```
.scol25, .mcol25, .lcol25 {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin-right:-3px;
  margin-top:-4px;
  text-align:center;
  padding:0px;
}
```

At last you set the widths and height for each screen size to be able always to show four rows of four images (except on mobiles where is one image per row).

```
<div id="photo-grid">
<img id="img-1" class="photo" alt="alt-of-img"/>
...
<img id="img-16" class="photo" alt="alt-of-img"/>
</div>
```

Dont forget to remove the whitespaces between the `<img>` tags so that you have no blank space.

PS. the `margin-top:-4px` i added because it wouldnt work on the online compilers, so when you add it to your page you can remove the command.

Hope it helps.

Link: [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/dyg5stor/)

If the link doesnt show you the code please tell me.